# Need help converting pseudo code to an 80x86 Assembly language program with the MASM assembler

Tags: arrays, assembly, visual-studio-2012, masm

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, editing the .asm file inside a windows32 solution.

This is the pseudo code that needs to be changed into assembly:

```
Declare a 32-bit integer array A[10] in memory

repeat
Prompt for and input user's array length L
until 0 <= L <= 10

for i := 0 to (L-1)
Prompt for and input A[i]
end for

while (First character of prompted input string for searching = 'Y' or 'y')
Prompt for and input value V to be searched
found := FALSE
  for i := 0 to (L-1)
    if V = A[i] then
found := TRUE
break
    end if
  end for

  if (found) then
Display message that value was found at position i
  else
Display message that value was not found
  end if
end while
```

I can manage the inputs, loops, and jumps well enough but the things tripping me up are making the array have a length that the user inputs, and running through the array to compare the values. What would help me out the most is if someone would make and explain a segments of code to help me understand the parts I'm not getting. I've tried searching for it online but nearly everything I've come across uses a different assembler making it hard to dissect.

My code thus far is:

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT
INCLUDE io.h            ; header file for input/output
.STACK 4096

.DATA
lengthA DWORD   ?
promptL BYTE    "Please enter a length of the array between 0 and 10: ", 0
string  BYTE    40 DUP (?)
A       DWORD   0  DUP (?)

.CODE
_MainProc PROC

Reread: input   promptL, string, 40     ; read ASCII characters
        atod    string                  ; convert to integer
        ;while (promptL < 0 or > 10)
            cmp eax, 0
            jl  Reread
            cmp eax, 10
            jg  Reread
        ;end while
        mov     lengthA, eax            ; store in memory

_MainProc ENDP
END                             ; end of source code
```

After checking that the user input is within range I just hit a brick wall and am not sure how to set up the array A to have the specified length or even if I declared A correctly.

Comment: You already have your array, it has a fixed size. It's up to you how much of it you use.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the assembly-time constant at runtime. The `DUP` directive is that, assembly-time directive reserving memory space by emitting the "init" value as many times, as you want, into resulting machine code. That forms a fixed executable, which is limited to that size used during assembling.

As your maximum L is 10, you can reserve array for the maximum possible size:

```
A       DWORD   10  DUP (?)
```

And then later in the code you will have to fetch the `[lengthA]` to know how many elements are used (to make it look as dynamically resized array and to not process remaining unused part of that reserve after address `A`).

Other option is to reserve memory dynamically at runtime, either by calling OS service for allocation of heap memory, or reserving the array on stack. But both options are considerably more advanced than using the fixed-size memory like above.

I don't see in your pseudo code any request for dynamic memory allocation, the solution with fixed size array looks OK to me, especially if you are struggling with it already, then you are probably not ready to program your own dynamic memory manager/allocator.

EDIT: Actually the pseudo code does specify you should reserve fixed size memory, I somehow overlooked it at first read:

```
Declare a 32-bit integer array A[10] in memory
```

So example of pseudo code using the `[lengthA]`:

```
    ; for i := 0 to (L-1)
    xor     edi,edi         ; index i
input_loop:
    cmp     edi,[lengthA]
    jge     input_loop_ends ; if (i >= L), end for

    ; TODO: Prompt for and input A[i]
    ; eax = input value, preserve edi (!)
    mov     [A + 4*edi],eax ; store value into A[i]

    ; end for
    inc     edi             ; ++i
    jmp     input_loop

input_loop_ends:
    ; memory at address A contains L many DWORD values from user
```